# Rest Web Services without Configuring web.xml using @ApplicationPath

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am facing issue in connecting to databse!!!
I have added the ojdbc14.jar but somehow it is not capturing the jar.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyJaxApp] in context with path [/develop-without-web.xml] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at MyResource.fun(MyResource.java:33)
```

Comment: Are you sure you've added the `ojdbc14.jar` to the classpath?

Comment: Yes i added but somehow tomcat is not finding it..

I created freshly Dynamic Web Project and before adding ojdbc14.jar i was getting the same error.

But putting ojdbc14.jar in Web-Inf lib folder resolved the issue

But for web services i am unable to resolve the error.

Comment: My mistake it worked correctly this time.